# punctuation check

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

I'd would like someone to check the punctuation and structure on the below sentence I've written.

Also, to confirm, the part 'to such a degree...' acts as an infinitive adverb phrase modifying the verb adorned telling us 'how' it is adorned.

> For the wedding at Mt Sunnex, the King's outfit was adorned with the widest array of bejeweled accoutrements and trinkets, to such a degree that it was awfully garish, making my head throb at the sight.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not a free proofreading service, however. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] to see if your question can be reformulated.

Comment: *To such a degree* is prepositional phrase. And perhaps reformat your question. But....  *For the wedding at Mt. Sunnex, the King's outfit was adorned with such a garish array of bejeweled accoutrements and trinkets that my head throbbed at the sight.*

Answer (score 1):

Remember your period after “Mt.”
An adverbial infinitive phrase should begin with “to” then modify a simple verb, then give us a “why”, in one form of usage. It would not need a comma unless it was introducing a main clause.
That is not the way your paragraph reads. I would simply remove the comma after “trinkets”.
If you wanted to use the AIP, you could say, “For the wedding at Mt. Sunnex, the King’s outfit, adorned with the widest array of bejeweled accoutrements and trinkets, was enough to make my head throb at the awful and garish sight.